# How to add space between items in a ReorderableListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
  return ReorderableListView(
      children: [
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
          ListTile(
            key: Key('$index'),
            title: Text('Item $index'),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
    );
```

Is there a way to add some spacing between each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap ListTile with Padding like below,

```
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0) //your choice
        ListTile(
          key: Key('$index'),
          title: Text('Item $index'),
        ),
      )
```